# MPI spawns all processes on master node

Tags: python, python-3.x, multiprocessing, mpi, mpi4py

Here's my code:

```
import sys
sys.path.append("/apps/anaconda3/pkgs/qgis-3.8.1-py37h59d211b_0/lib")
import qgis
import os
from qgis.core import *
from mpi4py import MPI
from timeit import default_timer as dt
import numpy as np


# Initialize MPI
comm = MPI.COMM_WORLD
rank = int(comm.Get_rank())

if(rank==0):
    print("Project loaded successfully")

# counter function
def counter(feats,vectors,rank):
    cnt = 0
    for feature in feats:
        cands = vectors.getFeatures(QgsFeatureRequest().setFilterRect(feature.geometry().boundingBox()))
        for area_feature in cands:
            if feature.geometry().intersects(area_feature.geometry()):
                cnt+=1
    return cnt

start = MPI.Wtime()

# loading layers
layer_ids = list(project.mapLayers().keys())
vec = layer_ids[0]
vectorlayer = project.mapLayers()[vec]
grid = QgsVectorLayer("/home/600.shp", "grid", "ogr")

# define number of jobs
cores = comm.size()

# split data
gfeats = np.array(list(grid.getFeatures()))
subs = np.array_split(gfeats,cores)

# start process based on rank
print("rank : ",rank," len : ",len(sub[rank]))
value = counter(subs[rank],vectorlayer,rank)

ttime = MPI.Wtime()-start


# perform the reductions:
tcount = comm.reduce(value,op=MPI.SUM, root=0)
tstime = comm.reduce(ttime, op=MPI.MAX, root=0)

# Print on rank 0 
if rank == 0:
    print(' Rank 0: count =    ',tcount)
    print(' Rank 0: time  =    ',tstime)
```

Executed Using:

```
mpiexec -n 50 python mptest.py
```

- In the code, I'm splitting the array into a number of processes I've mentioned, let's suppose 50, using np.array_split()
- After, I'm using rank as an index and executing only that split part in each process(or rank).
- HPC contains 5 nodes each with 24 cores.
- On running the code, the time is same as when I've used multiprocessing module in python
- which means all processes are spawning on a single node.

How can I use all 5 nodes, to execute this code and bring up maximum parallelization?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: are you using a resource manager? if not, you have to use a `machine file`.simply run `mpiexec -n 50 hostname| sort -u` to figure out how many nodes you are running on.

Comment: Can you write a clear solution or procedure. Cuz, i cannot find clear procedure to this. Like what should be the content of this machine file and how to attach it in execution command...etc

Comment: This is MPI implementation specific. But feel free to point me to an unclear procedure to this.

Comment: "mpiexec -n 50 hostname| sort -u" On running this, the output is master. and nothing else. Can you tell me how can i create a machine file?

Comment: you can create a machine file with the text editor of your choice.

Comment: BUT, I've the hpc shows only 1 single host, on running command right. So, what  should be the hostnames in host file